# Users table to Users and User Preferences. Is this normalized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalization

I have a table called `Users` that has a growing list of preferences. These preferences could includes ReligionId (which would key off to another table that contains the list of religions).

The list of preferences is growing. I want to split it off the `Users` table into 2 tables. The strategy that I think would work well is to make a separate table called `UserPreferences`. I'm wondering if doing this is in line with the rules of normalization. Here is an illustration to make things a bit more clear.

[image]

Is this normalized? Are there better ways? All comments appreciated.

EDIT: How UserPreferences key off to other tables:

[image]

Comment: I would not store SomePreference, AnotherPreference and another one in the same table. That looks like a table of preferences which should be normalized so that each preference is on its own row. I would recommend moving email and alternate email to another table also. That way you can have as many emails as you want. Also, I would recommend storing birthdate instead of age. You can calculate age on the fly against a static birthdate. If you store age the value is always stale.

Comment: @SeanLange What type of table setup would you suggest so that each preferences is on its own row? PrefId, Pref, PrefValue ? I agree with the rest of your comments and this is not the way my data is actually stored, this is just a representation for the sake of this question. I do actually store birthday and there is only 1 email address. Great comments though.

Comment: You are confusing "normalized" with "well designed". 1NF means using relations. You haven't given a non-relational design so you're not doing any normalization to 1NF. Further "normalization" to higher NFs is about replacing a table by smaller projections of it that join to it. That is not your problem here. So the issue is quality of design. But both your original and EAV designs are "bady designed" because their user rules ("predicates") for whether a row is in a table or query result and DBMS rules ("constraints") for whether the tables are valid are needlessly complicated.

Comment: @philipxy What do you think of Donal's answer below (please note the diagram)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum you could just have Users and Preferences. There should be a one to many relationship between users and preferences. One user can have many preferences. You could also split out the email addresses into another table - so that one user could have multiple email addresses - you can have a flag to denote the primary one. The DDL would look like:

```
    create table Users
    (
       UserId int,
       Age int
    )

    create table Preferences
    (
        PreferencesId int,
        UserId int,
        ReligionId int,
        PersonalDescription varchar(2000),
        HairColor int
    )

    create table EmailAddresses
    (
        EmailId int,
        UserId int,
        EmailAddress varchar(100),
        IsPrimary bit
    )

    create table Religion
    (
        ReligionId int,
        Name varchar(200)
    )

Insert into Religion (ReligionId, Name) Values (1, 'Jediism')
Insert into Religion (ReligionId, Name) Values (2, 'Sithism')
Insert into Religion (ReligionId, Name) Values (3, 'Yuuzhan Vong')
Insert into Religion (ReligionId, Name) Values (4, 'Pinacism')

Insert into Users (UserId, Age) Values (1, 30)
Insert into Users (UserId, Age) Values (2, 18)

Insert into Preferences (PreferencesId, UserId, ReligionId, PersonalDescription) values (1, 1, 1, 'a description')
Insert into Preferences (PreferencesId, UserId, ReligionId, PersonalDescription) values (2, 1, 4, 'another description')
Insert into Preferences (PreferencesId, UserId, ReligionId, PersonalDescription) values (3, 1, 4, 'even another description')
```

[image: Email table omitted]

Comment: Ok, I ran the query in SQL, looks good. One question: Couldn't PreferenceId in the Preferences table simply be removed? What's the point?

Comment: it is very important to have a primary key to identify rows. This should be unique. If you did not have this and you have 2 identical rows and you wanted to delete one - it would be very difficult without a unique primary key.

Comment: Yes for sure, that's one of the fundamental pillars of DBMS systems. However, each row could be uniquely identified with just UserId in the Preferences table. However, across the database, yes, it would take a combination of both UserId+PrefernceId to uniquely identify those records.

Comment: It is always best to have an not need something, than need and not have it :-)

Comment: I ran the diagram, minus the e-mail table. I believe some information could be stored in the Users table, like a single e-mail address, or age, or whatever is not a preference.

Comment: Closest thing to normalization + you provided a runnable query + you clarified a lot in these comments. Great answer.

Comment: Except that there is no normalization involved, and there is no justification for splitting the table anyway, and @user3308043 is right that PreferencesId adds nothing since UserId is a key.

Comment: @philipxy Meh. A bad solution to a bad problem. Works for me.

Comment: If each preference is listed like this why bother with a second table? You have a 1:1 relationship between Users and Preferences. You left of emails which I would roll to a second table but from this diagram the Preferences table is not necessary at all.

Comment: @SeanLange The problem is that this table is getting too wide. Extremely wide. It just needs to be split in some manner. Denormalization.

Answer (score 4):

Some folks are recommending to store the preferences one per row. This is called an Entity-Attribute-Value table, and it is *not* normalized. Some people say EAV is "more normalized," but they're mistaken. There is no rule of normalization that encourages EAV as a design in a relational database.

One practical way you can tell it's not normalized is that you can no longer use a foreign key constraint for your religion lookup table, if all values of all preferences share a single column in this preferences table. You can't make a foreign key constraint restrict the values only on rows for a particular preference type -- the FK constraint always applies to all rows in the table.
**Basically, Entity-Attribute-Value breaks SQL's support for constraints.**

The only normalized design is to define a separate column for each distinct preference. Then you can define data types and constraints appropriate to that preference type.

If you really want to understand relations and normalization, read [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code by C. J. Date](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316409).

Each column represents selections from a set. A set can be the set of integers, or the set of religions, or the set of email addresses. A row in a table is a pairing of sets that "go together," for example a given user has a name, and an birthdate, and a religion, and an email address, so those values are matched up together into one row, and together they describe something that exists in the world, i.e. a human being with those attributes.

What this means is that in each row, you have one value chosen for each of the columns, i.e. from each of the component sets that are references. And each column contains values *only* from one set. In the religion column, you can only choose religions, you can't also put favorite color and mother's maiden name and shoe size into the same column.

That's why EAV is bogus from a relational perspective, because it mashes values from any and all disparate attributes into the same column. It's more like a spreadsheet than a database. Not that I'm saying relational is the only way to store data. It's just that if you're asking if EAV is normalized, and normalization assumes as a prerequisite that the data is relational, then no, EAV is not relational and therefore cannot be normalized.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and I completely agree with your perspective. I'm trying to stay away from EAV and serialization. I have a DBMS and I figure I should use the power of the system in the way that it's meant to be used. However, in this case I'm running into a Users table that's getting too wide. Would simply splitting this table off be in line with the rules of normalization or perhaps be an acceptable form of denormalization? Maybe just a UserPreferences table with single primary key of UserId that holds all of this additional data? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Sometimes a non-relational solution is a more practical way to store the data, even though certain features of SQL are not supported. You might like my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).

Comment: Yes, it's starting to look like that. Great presentation. So this really *is* a scenario where the advantages and disadvantages have to be weighed and balanced.

Comment: Yes, most scenarios are like that! :-) There's rarely one single "right" answer that fits all projects, otherwise the alternatives wouldn't exist. There are tradeoffs to everything, and your job as a software engineer is to figure out if what you gain is more important than what you sacrifice. [#TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain't_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to split a single table in to two tables. Only time you split like this is *some users doesn't have Preferences at all*.

Creating a new column - whenever new **Preference** comes up - is not a good idea.

If you think **Preferences** will grow in the future, you can use the following method -

[image]

Comment: how about the preference value?

Comment: exactly what i was about to say

Comment: um, preferenceValue goes in the usersInPreferences table, not usersPreferences (it needs to go with a table with the preferenceID)

Comment: This doesn't cover the issue of different preference data types for Value. If all of my data types were nvarchar(50) this would be great.

Comment: @user3308043 **Based on your last update, you should not split the original table. Mainly, you have different data type for each column**. Splitting might look the original table clean at first, but it'll slow down your query. It is normal to have too many columns in a singe table in that case.

Comment: @Win Yes, this is what I'm getting at. Please see Bill Karwin's answer at the bottom. I'm trying to avoid the EAV model. However, let's say I add 100 preferences. My Users table will be wiiiide. I know that has the potential to slow queries and seems like it should be split.

Comment: @user3308043 I have seen some medical records with too many columns; it is hard to answer the question. If you think you can group some columns into **separate tables with PrimaryKey as UserId**, it will improve the speed.

Comment: Excellent. I think that's what I'm looking for. No composite key, just a touch of denormalization to reduce table size. Please read Bill Karwin's answer to see what I'm trying to avoid and for a good read.

Answer (score 1):

A normalized userPreference table would contain the userID, preferenceID, and preferenceValue.  Preferences would list all of your preferences (email, age, etc) on one row with an ID as the PK, plus whatever descriptive information you wanted to add.

---

since the data types of the preference values differ, you can declare it as a string/varchar, or, if you really want, have different preference values for the different data types, like 'prefValInt,' 'prefValChar,' etc., where only one column would contain a value.

I usually just use a string.

---

Now, if you want to enforce referential integrity, like in your example above, you're back to having each preferenceID in a different column, so you might want to keep those preferences in your main table and all of the other ones in the lookup table.

---

any column that needs RI enforced, such as religionID and hairColorID, can go in the user table, or can go in a userPreferenceRI table with a 1-1 relationship with the user table.  any column that does not have RI enforced, such as age, dateOfBirth, accountBalance, emailBody can go in a userPreference table with the PK being the userID and the preferenceID and a 1-many relationship with the user table.

HTH

---

you should also take into account the likelihood of preferences existing.  For required fields, such as ageAtPointInTime or dateOfBirth, you should store them in the user table.  For preferences which are sparsely populated (most don't have an answer,) you should put them in a lookup table.

```
    user: userID, requiredFld1, requiredFld2
    preference: preferenceID, preferenceName, preferenceDescription
    userPreference: userID, preferenceID, userPreferenceVal as varchar(100) 
(list of columns never changes)
    userPreferenceRelated: userID, religionID, hairColorID, otherPreferenceID 
(list of columns grows over time)
```

Comment: It's this preferenceValue column that's problematic. It would have to be one data type and one data type only.

Comment: I get that you usually just use string, but this is defeating the purpose of having a database that is capable of different data types.

Comment: I mean, you have to have referential integrity. That's why DBMS systems exists. That's why PK/FK exists. The whole issue is that the main table is ballooning in size.

Comment: if you want to enforce RI, you need to have the preference value in its own column which can be in the user table.  If you're just storing descriptive text (varchar(200)) or dates, you can store them in the userPreferences table.  There can be trade-offs with RDBMSs, you know.  If it was subject to a hard-and-fast set of rules, they wouldn't pay us too much.

Comment: Ok, so you're suggesting I initially use things as they are (the original table on the left in my diagram)? And the userPreferences table holds text/dates?

Comment: Yeah you're really edging on exactly what I'm looking for with your suggestion of a userPreferenceRI table. Do you think you could run a quick SQL CREATE query to give me a visual example of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you have growing preferences then I would suggest you make a new table for preferences and add the FKey to the UserPreferences

Users Table - userid, email, age, alternateemail ...

Preferences table - Preferenceid, preference_Value, active, required

Users Preferences table - userid, preferenceid, preference_data

Now you can have your ever growing list of preferences in the Preferences table and connect it to the UI, and the two columns - active, and required will help you to control your form easily from backend.

And in user preferences table you just reference the preference id with the user id and store the data input by the user for that preference.

I hope this was clear.

Comment: Most of it was, but what would preference_value store and what would preference_data store?

Comment: preference value holds the name of the preference. ex in you form you have - "Relationship Status" so this is a preference_value. And the preference_data is the user input for this preference eg - "Single".

Sorry about the naming convention.

Comment: This is EAV-style. You're throwing out every reason that you're using a relational database. Please see Bill Karwin's answer.