# PostgreSQL: JSON column or one-to-many table for config options

Tags: postgresql, database-normalization

We currently have a table which stores information about users. Some of the columns hold information such as user ID, name etc., but many other columns (booleans, integers and varchars etc) hold configuration options for each user.

This has over time resulted in the width of the table becoming quite big and I think the time has come to migrate this to something new, so I want to remove all the "option"-related columns to a separate data structure.

The typical way of doing this, from my experience, would be to have a new table which would simply have `option_id` and `option_name`, and a second new table which would contain `user_id`, `option_id`, `option_value`, for example.

However, a colleague suggested using the new [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) column type as an alternative, but I don't know if I like the idea of storing relational data in a non-relational way. From a Java point of view, it's pretty much the same as far as I can tell - it'll just be turned into a POJO and then cached on the object.

I should mention the number of users will be quite low, only going into the thousands, and number of columns could and will go into the hundreds.

Does anyone have advice on the best way forward here?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you have already de-normalized your database structure by adding columns to a table that are irrelevant to some of the entities stored therein.

Using JSON is just another way to de-normalize, cramming a bunch of values into a single row-column field. The excellent [binary support for JSON in Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#JSONB_Binary_JSON_storage) (the [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html) data type) then lets you index elements within those JSON documents, as a way to quickly access those embedded values. This is quite screwy from a relational point of view, but is handy for some situations.

Either approach is commonly done for this kind of problem, and is not necessarily bad. In general, de-normalizing is often a pay-now-or-pay-later kind of solution. But for something like user preferences, there may not be a pay-later penalty, as there often is with most business-oriented problem domains.

Nevertheless, you should consider a normalized database structure.

By the way, this kind of table-structure Question might be better asked in the sister site, http://DBA.StackExchange.com/.

I suggest searching Stack Overflow, that DBA site, and the wider Internet for discussions of database design for storing user preferences. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25536617/642706).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure any of the columns are "irrelevant" - they are all directly related to users, which is why the information is in the users table. What sort of normalized structure would you recommend?

Comment: @Kieran You should clarify that fact in your Question. Your first sentence led me to believe you have some setting for some users in some fields, other settings for other users in other fields, and still other settings for other purposes in other fields. Make clear that *all* the fields in your wide table do indeed apply to each and every user. And rewrite that first sentence for clarity as it’s meaning continues to escape me after three readings.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough, given that it started with "We currently have a table which stores information about users", but I've edited it nonetheless, so hopefully it's  a bit clearer now.